# How to use super to initialize all the parents when using multiple inheritance

Tags: python

[How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

I was looking at the above question/answers and made myself really confused

```
 53 class First(object):
 54     def __init__(self):
 55         print "first"
 56
 57 class Second(First):
 58     def __init__(self):
 59         super(Second, self).__init__()
 60         print "second"
 61
 62 class Third(First):
 63     def __init__(self):
 64         print "third"
 65
 66 class Fourth(Second, Third):
 67     def __init__(self):
 68         super(Fourth, self).__init__()
 69         print "thats it"
```

> > Fourth()
> >     third
> >     second
> >     thats it

```
 53 class First(object):
 54     def __init__(self):
 55         print "first"
 56
 57 class Second(First):
 58     def __init__(self):
 59         #super(Second, self).__init__()         <---- commented out
 60         print "second"
 61
 62 class Third(First):
 63     def __init__(self):
 64         print "third"
 65
 66 class Fourth(Second, Third):
 67     def __init__(self):
 68         super(Fourth, self).__init__()
 69         print "thats it"
```

> > Fourth()
> >     second
> >     thats it

Could someone explain to me what's happening behind the scene in regards to why the top prints `"third"` and the bottom one doesn't?

I feel like there is some sort of order/sequence that's happening behind the scene that I am not seeing.

--
Fourth.**mro**

commented out super in Second
(, , , , )

super in Second
(, , , , )

Comment: maybe a duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277367/832621)?

Comment: @SaulloCastro but thats the question that I linked to...

Comment: @ealeon Look at `Fourth.__mro__`, that's the order `super()` follows.

Comment: @George The OP was saying he didn't understand how the explanation in the linked question would apply to this situation.

Comment: I will vote to reopen your question after editing it a little bit since the title misleads us to think it is a duplicate...

Comment: @hcwhsa yes but __mro__ is the same regardless whether Second has super() or not? how does something that's in Second affects whether Third gets invoked or not?

Comment: @ealeon `super()` call in `Second` invokes next item in MRO, not super of `Second`. That's how Mixins work. Read: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: @hcwhsa so desipte its __mro__ being the same, super() call the next item in MRO which is Third, whereas without super, the next item in MRO would not be called and hence with super, third gets invoked. Okay this part makes sense. So, this is saying that not all items in MRO gets invoked? And if i add super in Third, First will get invoked since its the next item in MRO.

Comment: But even if Third has super, it will be not called if Second does not have super since Third will never be invoked... hmm..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super` doesn't actually call the super class. It calls the next method according to the Method Resolution Order (MRO). It looks like the MRO for your example classes is as follows:

```
Fourth
Second
Third
First
```

That is, using `super` from `Fourth` gets you a method on `Second`. Using `super` from `Second` gets you a method on `Third`. etc.

In the first example:

1. `Fourth.__init__` is called.
2. `Fourth.__init__` calls `Second.__init__` via `super`.
3. `Second.__init__` calls `Third.__init__` via `super`.
4. `Third.__init__` prints "third"
5. `Second.__init__` prints "second"
6. `Fourth.__init__` prints "that's it".

In the second example:

1. `Fourth.__init__` is called.
2. `Fourth.__init__` calls `Second.__init__` via `super`.
3. `Second.__init__` prints "second"
4. `Fourth.__init__` prints "that's it".

So, yes, changing a `super` call in `Second` changes whether something on `Third` is called, even though `Third` is not a super class of `Second`. This is indeed confusing. I recommend reading ["Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it"](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). That's the explanation I read that got the above to make sense to me.

Comment: Another related article: [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Answer (score 4):

The MRO is not a nested hierarchy. It is a flat list that obeys a set of constraints, namely that each class must precede its base classes, and those base classes must exist in the same order relative to each other as they are mentioned in the subclass declaration.

By printing `Fourth.__mro__`, we can see the MRO in your examples is:

```
(<class '__main__.Fourth'>, 
<class '__main__.Second'>, 
<class '__main__.Third'>, 
<class '__main__.First'>, 
<type 'object'>)
```

Each call to `super` that is set off will call the next method in the MRO. You can think of the number of `super` calls as the zero indexed "depth" into the MRO to which you will descend.

Since there are two calls to `super` in the first snippet, `Second.__init__` and `Third.__init__` are called (in addition, of course, to the immediate class' init method). Similarly, in the second snippet you have a single call to `super`, which means only `Second.__init__` will be called.

Comment: How did you get that tuple output?

Comment: @NealEhardt `print Fourth.__mro__`